# i18n marked as duplicated content on Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, wordpress, internationalization, woocommerce

We have an e-commerce website running on **Wordpress** with **Woocommerce**, **WPML** & **Yoast SEO**.

Our website is currently translated in 2 languages:

- French (on `/`)
- English (on `/en`)

Our slugs are translated:

- `/boutique` (FR) become `/en/shop` (EN)
- `/produit/sample` (FR) become `/en/product/sample`
- etc

On every page, we have the current meta:

```
<html lang="fr-FR">
  <head>
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-fr" href="https://example.org">
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="https://example.org/en/">
  </head>
</html>
```

Where `fr-FR` is the current language and the URLs in href correspond to the related URLs in other languages.

Yoast SEO auto-generate the sitemap with URLs (for every languages).

The problem is that Google mark our pages as duplicated and reference only one language.

For some pages such as `/produit/sample` (`/en/product/sample`) Google choose the english URL and for some such as `/boutique` (`/shop`) Google choose the french URL.

What can we do to avoid this problem of duplicated content ?
Actually we only have the english version referenced on Google (and for some pages, french version).

**Example of a page marked as duplicated in Google Search Console :**
[image: Screenshot of a page in Google Search Console] (I was not able to get the english version..)

Comment: How do you see Google mark pages as duplicate?  Are you looking in Google search console and seeing Google choosing canonical URLs on its own?

Comment: Google usually sees different languages as different content.   There may be something wrong from a technical perspective.  Have you verified using Google's URL inspection that Googlebot is seeing the content in the correct languages on the correct URLs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've added a screenshot of a page in Google Search Console. Sorry, i wasn't able to get the english version. @StephenOstermiller